# How to ignore a folder and its contents in git?

Tags: git

I have a folder in wordpress called wp-content and a subfolder called cache. The cache folder also has folders and files inside it.

The location of my .gitignore file is inside my root directory.

The current code that I use to ignore the `wp-content/cache` and the contents inside it is:

```
wp-content/cache/*
```

The line above does not work. Do you know the correct way? Thanks

Comment: The tags javascript and worpress are not relevant for this question (I tried to edit and remove them). The problematics of the question involve git and git only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the syntax you used should work, you can try:

```
/wp-content/cache/*
```

In case the directory you are trying to ignore has already been committed previously, be sure to remove it first, and then see if your `.gitignore` entry has any effect for new changes.

Comment: it still detects the files inside the cache folder. i think this is because this folder was committed before

Comment: In that case commit removing the directory first, and then see if your .gitignore entry affects new changes. Probably your original entry should have worked just fine too.

Comment: your suggestion about removing the directory first worked. thank you

Comment: You don't have to delete the dir. for future reference: `git rm --cached /wp-content/cache/*` will just delete the files from gits cache.

Answer (score 3):

I think the syntax is just

```
wp-content/cache/
```

in your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

Try `wp-content/cache/*` or `wp-content/cache/` in your `.gitignore` file